# Investment value calculator

Tags: java, javafx

This is supposed to be an investment value calculator using JavaFX, and I got most of the code working. I just can't get it to properly show the future value amount. Despite calling `tfFutureValue.setText`, I do not see the expected value in the field. It remains blank.

Simply compile and run the program, enter numbers in the editable fields and click the "Calculate" button. The expected result is that the future value is displayed in the non-editable field as a calculation result. But the field still looks blank, despite me setting a text value.

Any help would be appreciated, I've been at it for a while can't seem to understand what is wrong.

```java
public class InvestCalc extends Application {
    
    private TextField tfInvestmentAmount = new TextField();
    private TextField tfNumYears = new TextField();
    private TextField tfAnnualIntRate = new TextField();
    private TextField tfFutureValue = new TextField();
    private Button btCalculate = new Button("Calculate");
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setHgap(5);
        gridPane.setVgap(5);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Investment Amount: "), 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(tfInvestmentAmount, 1, 0);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Number of Years: "), 0, 1);
        gridPane.add(tfNumYears, 1, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Annual Intrest Rate: "), 0, 2);
        gridPane.add(tfAnnualIntRate, 1, 2);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Future Value: "), 0, 3);
        gridPane.add(tfFutureValue, 1, 3);
        gridPane.add(btCalculate, 1, 4);
        
        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
        tfInvestmentAmount.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        tfNumYears.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        tfAnnualIntRate.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        tfFutureValue.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        tfFutureValue.setEditable(false);
        GridPane.setHalignment(btCalculate, HPos.RIGHT);
        
        btCalculate.setOnAction(e -> calculateInvestment());
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 400, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Investment Calculator");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    private void calculateInvestment() {
        double annualIntrest = Double.parseDouble(tfAnnualIntRate.getText());
        int numYears = Integer.parseInt(tfNumYears.getText());
        double investAmount = Double.parseDouble(tfInvestmentAmount.getText());
        
        double value = investAmount * Math.pow(1 + annualIntrest, numYears *12);
        
        tfFutureValue.setText("$%.2f" + value);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: What leads you to believe something is wrong? A compile error? A runtime error? An answer that your teacher says is wrong? "I can't understand what is wrong" is not a question.

Comment: I have voted to reopen. You want `setText(String.format("%.2f", value))`, you forgot the formatter call. You also should omit the "$", because the fields above do not have any currencies either. The formula works independently of currency. `numYears * 12` if wrong, too, because above you enter a number of years, not months. I also recommend to let the user input the interest rate in percent, i.e. for 3% she should enter "3", not be required to enter "0.03". Then the formula would be `investAmount * Math.pow(1 + annualInterest * 0.01, numYears)`. BTW, the spelling is "interest", not "intrest".

Comment: @kriegaex wondering why you want this reopened? If the forgotten format really is the problem (which the asker didn't state clearly), it'll probably be closed again as typo. If it's also the incorrect calc it's too broad. Both are unrelated to fx. To make it related to fx and make it useful for future readers would require to solve both first, and afterwards implement a solution involving a TextFormatter ;)

Comment: I didn't say that it is a typo. IMO, the OP is simply beginner in programming. You see, he cannot even get a basic formula to calculate the interest right. So I would like to help him, writing a comprehensive answer and post a fully functional version of his program. I spent a little while to do this locally and want to avoid having wasted my time, too. At least he can accept my answer and be happy that someone helped him, instead of just closing his question despite reproducible example, just because his explanation of the problem was bad. BTW, I just want to be nice to a newbie.

Comment: @kriegaex agreed: looks like a very new programmer, but that doesn't mean we should spoon-feed them (their first learning item is to separate the problems, then do some research - coursebook, tutorials, java doc). When stuck on any of those, they should come back with a [mcve] demonstrating the concrete issue of _that single problem_.

Comment: @kriegaex This site is _not_ a personal helpdesk but a builder for community knowledge. So what would a future reader/searcher will get from an answer (even if it's very good per each part of the question)  to this mixture of errors? Would they want to get a formula right? Or want an example of formatting a string (via plain java api)? Or are they attracted by the domain investment? Personally, I think that this question is unsalvable, suspect that you disagree, though :).

Comment: Thanks for lecturing me about your personal view of which questions deserve answers here. I myself close-vote often (but never down-vote), usually if there is no [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but not because someone is a beginner unable to articulate his question properly. At least he deserves respect for providing the MCVE without anyone even asking, i.e. he let his code speak. That deserves more than you looking down on him for that or on me for trying to help him. Just because you possess knowledge, it does not mean he does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a working version:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>SO_Java_JavaFxRefreshFieldValue_71812697</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.8</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>InvestCalc</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>17.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Run via 'mvn javafx:run'
 */
public class InvestCalc extends Application {
  private TextField tfInvestmentAmount = new TextField();
  private TextField tfNumYears = new TextField();
  private TextField tfAnnualIntRate = new TextField();
  private TextField tfFutureValue = new TextField();
  private Button btCalculate = new Button("Calculate");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.setHgap(5);
    gridPane.setVgap(5);
    gridPane.add(new Label("Investment Amount: "), 0, 0);
    gridPane.add(tfInvestmentAmount, 1, 0);
    gridPane.add(new Label("Number of Years: "), 0, 1);
    gridPane.add(tfNumYears, 1, 1);
    gridPane.add(new Label("Annual Interest Rate [%]: "), 0, 2);
    gridPane.add(tfAnnualIntRate, 1, 2);
    gridPane.add(new Label("Future Value: "), 0, 3);
    gridPane.add(tfFutureValue, 1, 3);
    gridPane.add(btCalculate, 1, 4);
    gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);

    tfInvestmentAmount.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    tfNumYears.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    tfAnnualIntRate.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    tfFutureValue.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    tfFutureValue.setEditable(false);
    GridPane.setHalignment(btCalculate, HPos.RIGHT);

    Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 400, 250);

    btCalculate.setOnAction(e -> calculateInvestment());

    primaryStage.setTitle("Investment Calculator");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private void calculateInvestment() {
    double annualInterest = Double.parseDouble(tfAnnualIntRate.getText());
    int numYears = Integer.parseInt(tfNumYears.getText());
    double investAmount = Double.parseDouble(tfInvestmentAmount.getText());
    double value = investAmount * Math.pow(1 + annualInterest * 0.01, numYears);
    tfFutureValue.setText(String.format("%.2f", value));
  }
}
```

Now run the program with `mvn javafx:run`. Let's find out the future value for an investment of 1000 for 2 years with 3% interest:

[image: screenshot]

That looks correct. So what was wrong?

The main problem was this line which tries to concatenate a format string and a double value:

```java
tfFutureValue.setText("$%.2f" + value);
```

The correct version is:

```java
tfFutureValue.setText(String.format("%.2f", value));
```

I also suggest to tell the user to enter the interest as a percent value rather than a floating point number between 0 and 1, because this is what most people expect:

```java
gridPane.add(new Label("Annual Interest Rate [%]: "), 0, 2);
```

And then divide by 100 in the formula. Also fix the bug that we are asking for a number of years but the original code was trying to calculate based on months:

```java
double value = investAmount * Math.pow(1 + annualInterest * 0.01, numYears);
```